# Is there is a way to use reactive data.frame, renderplot, and observeEvent to toogle points within a shinny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

In a shiny app, I upload a data set, which is set as reactive (because it can be updated and replace by another), and plot a lm model while using ggplot2.

I am only displaying a small part of the code to make it simple. **I understand that the problems if due to the use of `reactive()` function within `observeEvent()`**. But I do not know **how to fix this** issue.

This works well. See the part of the code below within ui, and server.

```
#in ui
fluidRow(column(2,numericInput("Xmin", "Xmin:", -0.2, step = 0.1)),
column(2,numericInput("Xmax", "Xmax:", 2, step = 0.1)),
column(2,numericInput("Ymin", "Ymin:", -0.2, step = 0.5)),
column(2,numericInput("Ymax", "Ymax:", 20, step = 0.5))),
plotOutput("plot_gam", click = "plot1_click",   brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush")),
actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
```

```
#in server
    #PLOT MODEL
    dg <- reactive({dat() %>% select(A,B)})
    vals <- reactive({reactiveValues(keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(dg())))})

    keep    <- reactive({dg()[ vals()$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]})
    exclude <- reactive({dg()[!vals()$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]})
  
    output$plot_gam <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(keep(), aes(A, B)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "red") +
    geom_point(data = exclude(), shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(input$Xmin, input$Xmax),   ylim = c(input$Ymin,input$Ymax))
    })
```

Now I wish to be able to toggle points.

```
    # Toggle points that are clicked
   observeEvent(input$plot1_click, 
   {req(vals())
   res <- nearPoints(dg(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)
   vals()$keeprows <- xor(vals()$keeprows, res$selected_)
    })

  # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
  req(vals())
    res <- brushedPoints(dg(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
   vals()$keeprows <- xor(vals()$keeprows, res$selected_)
 })

  # Reset all points
  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
  req(vals())
    vals()$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(dg()))
  })
```

Unfortunately the app crash while I try to toggle. and I got the following message

`Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment`

Comment: There is no need to wrap a `reactiveValues` inside a `reactive`, i.e. try `vals <- reactiveValues(...)` and after doing so do `vals$keeprows` instead of `vals()$keeprows`.

Comment: @stefan, I should have mentioned that I already tried this. It returns this error, moreover does not allow me to launch the app. `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.`

Comment: Okay. The issue is that you use `dg()` when you init the `reactiveValues`. Try with separating into two steps, i.e. do `vals <- reactiveValues(keeprows = NULL)` and init `vals` using an `observeEvent`, i.e. `observeEvent(dg(), {vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(dg())})`

Comment: @stefan It works perfectly. I understood that something like "circular" caused troubles, but I would not have thought at your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to @stefan respond in comments above, here is the solution :

```
    vals <- reactiveValues(keeprows = NULL)
    observeEvent(dg(), {vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(dg()))})
    
    keep    <- reactive({dg()[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]})
    exclude <- reactive({dg()[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]})
```